# Function not returning the volume value

Tags: javascript, function, invoke

i was wondering why this function its not working as far as my understanding goes(newbie) when invoking i should have the `value[0]` and `[1]` in order to get the result that i am  looking for but i have tried in the browser and in console.log and i am not getting the [1] return value as expected.

```
function getSize(width, height, depth) {
    var area = width * height;
    var volume = width * height * depth;
    var sizes = [area, volume];
    alert(area);
}

var areaOne = getSize(3, 2, 1)[0];
var volumeOne = getSize(2, 1, 5)[1];
```

Comment: The function is missing a `return` statement, where you supposed to return the `sizes` array. Try adding `return sizes` after the alert statement.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are missing `return`.

A function should always return value.

```
function getSize(width,height,depth){
  var area =width * height;
  var volume=width*height*depth;
  var sizes=[area,volume];
  //alert(area);
  return area;
}
var areaOne=getSize(3,2,1)[0];
var volumeOne=getSize(2,1,5)[1];

console.log(volumeOne)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return the value form you function in order to retrieve the values.

```js
function getSize(width,height,depth){
var area =width * height;
var volume=width*height*depth;
var sizes=[area,volume];
return [volume, area]; // you should reuren the value in order to get it
}
var areaOne=getSize(3,2,1)[0];
var volumeOne=getSize(2,1,5)[1];
console.log(areaOne, volumeOne);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function doesn't have a return parameter, in order to assign functions output (in this case sizes[] array) your function needs to return that value, just add `return sizes;` at the end of your function definition.